# Markdown-to-jsx not accepting source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, markdown, react-context

I am using one of the Material UI templates for blog posts: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/blog.
I created my React app with npx create-react-app.

When I console log the source it comes out as a string, when I add it in the markdown-to-jsx it shows me this error index.module.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default(...) is not a function.`

Steps to reproduce:

create an app with npx create-react-app

import the material UI template written on the above link

use `fetch(post1).then(res => res.text()).then(text=>setMarkdown(text))` inside a useEffect hook to get the markdown text.

Add the markdown state in the way that the template used it here

```
<Markdown className={classes.markdown} key={markdown.substring(0, 40)}>
         {markdown}
       </Markdown>
```

and the error happens

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

What I have tried basically boils down to changing the MD file to a js string export default, changing markdown-to-jsx versions, and trying different attribute options on the markdown-to-jsx library but none is working and I am lost.

Comment: Possible solution for someone trying to do a hack job but which does not answer the base problem:
This is the sandbox material ui has https://codesandbox.io/s/2p9049nlrj?file=/src/Markdown.js:182-264
Use import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown"; with Reactmardkwon@3.6.0 and change the options into renders as described above but this still does not answer the base problem.